# Validate URL entered by user

Tags: javascript

I have already checked previous answers on the SO. I know they are cool.

Here is my chance:
I am taking values of textbox and passing it to function to validate. It passes url correctly but not doing validations. Can someone check where is the bug? I could not identify

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>ThenWat</title>
    <script>@Vicky: above regex does not filter: 

    function validateURL($URL) {
      alert($URL);
      $pattern_1 = "/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i";
      $pattern_2 = "/^(www)((\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i";       

      if(preg_match($pattern_1, $URL) || preg_match($pattern_2, $URL)){
        alert("correct");
        return true;
      } else{
        alert("Incorrect");
        return false;
      }
    }

    </script>
        </head>
   <body style="height: 560px">
        <form>

            <label>Enter URL: <input type="text" value="http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html" name="sent" id="t1" style="width: 400px; height:40px;"  ></label><br/>

            <div style="z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 160px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">  <button onclick="validateURL(document.getElementById('t1').value)";> Fire me </button>      
            </div>
         </form>


   </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

```
 <html>
       <head>
          <title>ThenWat</title>
        <script>@Vicky: above regex does not filter: 

        function validateURL($URL) {

var str=$URL;; 
var n=str.match(/((https?\:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+)(\w{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/g);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;

//alert("correct or incorrect as per validation");      how to do this?
        }

        </script>
            </head>
       <body style="height: 560px">
            <form>

                <label>Enter URL: <input type="text" value="http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html" name="sent" id="t1" style="width: 400px; height:40px;"  ></label><br/>

                <div style="z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 160px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">  <button onclick="validateURL(document.getElementById('t1').value)";> Fire me </button>      
                </div>
             </form>


       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There is no `preg_match` function in JavaScript, unless you define it somewhere else.

Comment: You should use `onsubmit` on `<form>` instead. It is also called when the user simply presses the enter key in the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str="The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var n=str.match(/ain/g);
```

To match string with regular expression in javascript you need to use `match()`. Check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

regexp for URL : `/((https?\:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+)(\w{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/`

---

Update:

```
function myFunction(){
var str="http://www.google.com"; 
var regexp = /((https?\:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+)(\w{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/g;
 if(str.match(regexp)){
  alert("okay");
  }else{
  alert("not okay");
 }
}
```

regular expression library : https://github.com/javaquery/regexp/blob/master/regexp-0.0.1.js

Comment: thanks, your script work significantly current. I chkecked it on w3school editor. But after checking how can take appropriate action like alert() or show some message. Can you please currect the updated code in my question in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $pattern1.test($URL) or $pattern1.match($URL)instead of using preg_match($pattern_1, $URL)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function validateURL($URL) {
  alert($URL);
  $pattern_1 = /^(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i;
  $pattern_2 = /^(www)((\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+.(com|org|net|dk|at|us|tv|info|uk|co.uk|biz|se)$)(:(\d+))?\/?/i;

  if($pattern_1.test($URL) || $pattern_2.test($URL)){
    alert("correct");
    return true;
  } else{
    alert("Incorrect");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: preg_match function belongs to php, not javascript. If you are intentionally using php then enclose the function under php code tag.

Comment: I added `.html` in above regex but even `http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html` given as incorrect! my first test failed

Comment: I had assumed that you are not able to test the url but your regEx is working. So I had not tested the regEx. There are many flavors of regEx for url validation. Choose your flavor from http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20

Answer (score 0):

The problem for your is your regular expression

i have a pretty good one i normally use like this:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?
```

It checks first if something before the first . (ex. testing in testing.mywebsite.com) then checks mywebsite and last after the last dot it even checks the ending